# How do I render data from a multidimensional array using Handlebars?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, handlebars.js

guys. I'm just getting started with Handlebars, as such, my question might seem a tad 'nooby'. I have a two-dimensional array (it is the **data** in the first line) I'm supposed to loop through and render the information. Under normal circumstances, this is straightforward. However, the problem arises when trying to create the route path inside the second loop. The 'name' in `<p><a href="/polls/categories/{{name}}">{{title}}</a></p>` is supposed to be the same as the one in `<th scope="row">{{name}}</th>`. How do I escape the nested array(loop) to get the value corresponding to the 'name' key from the parent, **data**, array?

Here's a code snippet

```
{{#each data}}
<tr>
   <th scope="row">{{name}}</th>
   <td>
      {{#each polls}}
      <p><a href="/polls/categories/{{name}}">{{title}}</a></p>
      {{/each}}
   </td>
</tr>
{{/each}}
```

Here's part of the **data** array, for illustration purposes.

```
...,
category: 'Sports',
polls: [
    {
        title: 'Most hated team in the NBA',
        choices: ['Golden State Warriors', 'LA Lakers', 'Cleveland Cavaliers', 'New York Knicks', 'Boston Celtics'],
    },
    {
        title: 'Best (active) boxer pound for pound',
        choices: ['Roman Gonzalez', 'Terence Crawford', 'Andre Ward', 'Gennady Golovkin', 'Vasyl Lomachenko'],
    },
    {
        title: 'Greatest football (soccer) player of all time',
        choices: ['Lionel Messi', 'Diego Maradona', 'Johann Cruyff', 'Pele', 'Alfredo di Stefano'],
    }
],
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `../` syntax in Handlebars that allows you to use the parent context. Using that your `polls` loop should be:

```
{{#each polls}}
<p><a href="/polls/categories/{{../name}}">{{title}}</a></p>
{{/each}}
```

They have a similar example in their [official page](http://handlebarsjs.com/) that uses the same syntax:

```
<h1>Comments</h1>

<div id="comments">
  {{#each comments}}
  <h2><a href="/posts/{{../permalink}}#{{id}}">{{title}}</a></h2>
  <div>{{body}}</div>
  {{/each}}
</div>
```

Comment: Oh, thank you, man! Was just going through the official documentation but was kind of in hurry to get the code working.